# Post Form Value on Submit Click from Entity Framework Identity Scaffolded Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In my .cshtml file I have a form which works fine for my MVC pages:

```
            <form action="@Url.Action("SaveUserEntryAsync", "ConfirmEmail")" method="post">
                <label class="modal-body1 col-form-label" id="confirmEmailPageComingSoonModalFormLabel">Modal Error!3</label>
                <br />
                <textarea class="form-control" name="newsfeedUserEntry" id="newsfeedUserEntry" type="text"></textarea>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="ComingSoonModalFooterSubmitButton" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="confirmEmailPageComingSoonModal">@_loc[Model.Submit]</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

In my scaffolded cshtml.cs file I have a `public async Task<IActionResult> SaveUserEntryAsync(string newsfeedUserEntry)` method.

`<form action="@Url.Action("SaveUserEntryAsync", "ConfirmEmail")" method="post">` does not work with the Razor page and I cannot find the correct syntax so that my button works on the page. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: You should read about handler methods in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods, and then about how to use the asp-handler attribute on the form tag helper: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/form-tag-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Razor Pages, it uses razor pages and page handler. `@Url.Action()` targets to MVC controller and action. You could use `@Url.Page(string pageName, string pageHandler)`. Asume you have a `ConfirmEmail.cshtml` and `ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs`:

```
<form  method="post" action="@Url.Page("ConfirmEmail", "SaveUserEntry")" >
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()   
    <label class="modal-body1 col-form-label" id="confirmEmailPageComingSoonModalFormLabel">Modal Error!3</label>
    <br />
    <textarea class="form-control" name="newsfeedUserEntry" id="newsfeedUserEntry" type="text"></textarea>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="ComingSoonModalFooterSubmitButton" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="confirmEmailPageComingSoonModal">aaa</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Or you could use `asp-page` and `asp-page-handler` like below:

```
<form asp-page="ConfirmEmail" asp-page-handler="SaveUserEntry" method="post">
    <label class="modal-body1 col-form-label" id="confirmEmailPageComingSoonModalFormLabel">Modal Error!3</label>
    <br />
    <textarea class="form-control" name="newsfeedUserEntry" id="newsfeedUserEntry" type="text"></textarea>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="ComingSoonModalFooterSubmitButton" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="confirmEmailPageComingSoonModal">aaa</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Note: No need to add Async suffix in request url.**

For the handler, it shoud be `OnPostXXX`(XXX should be the handler name):

```
public class ConfirmEmailModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveUserEntryAsync(string newsfeedUserEntry)
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-handlers-per-page

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change `@Url.Action` instead of you have to use `@Url.Page` or use `asp-page` directly like @Rena says. and change your code:-

```
<button type="submit" id="ComingSoonModalFooterSubmitButton" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="confirmEmailPageComingSoonModal">aaa</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" id="ComingSoonModalFooterSubmitButton" data-dismiss="confirmEmailPageComingSoonModal" value=@_loc[Model.Submit] class="btn btn-success/>
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.